# Replace special and optional characters in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm learning regex and trying to work on a small task.

I am taking an input amount as string and converting it into dollar format.

The input string looks like this

```
123456.78
```

And the output string looks like this

```
$123,456.78
```

Using regex, I have tried to avoid leading zeros and commas that may be present in input amount using below regex. For example if input is like

```
000,000123456.78
```

```
String amount = amount.replaceFirst("^[0,]+(?!$)", "");
```

And I'm producing the output dollar format with

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US")).format(Float.parseFloat(amount));
```

**I'm not able to replace any other characters that may be present apart from the leading zeros. For example, if '$' is already present in the input I am facing an error with the conversion. I'm not sure how to handle this.**

Comment: I tried the same thing but somehow it doesn't match that $ and it is still present in there

Comment: Ok you can try: `amount.replaceAll("^[$0,]+", "");`

Comment: My bad, I didn't change it to replaceAll, now I am able to replace the $ character, thanks :)

Comment: Similary, is there any way to handle any other unwanted characters present and replace them??

Comment: ok in that case: `amount.replaceAll("^(?:0|[^\\d.])+", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following string.

```
String str = "000,000,000ab$k0b#wef$12322920292029202920456.78";
```

- first, get rid of the undesired leading characters including any $.
- then using a repeating regex, generate the proper commas. This could also be done by modifying the ',' with the locale symbol for numbers.
- then prepend a `$` to the result.

```
str = str.replaceAll("^([0$\\D]+)","");
System.out.println(str);
String result = "";
while (!str.equals(result)) {
     result = str;
     str = str.replaceAll("(\\d)(\\d\\d\\d)(?!\\d)", "$1,$2");
}
System.out.println("$" + result);
```

prints

```
12322920292029202920456.78
$12,322,920,292,029,202,920,456.78
```

Comment: I don't think this takes care of other kind of inputs which may have unwanted characters

Comment: @adamn2  You gave an input and  an expected output.  If there are other requirements then you need to give those examples and show the input and expected output.  Otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: So for example, it might not work for the above code if the input is $123456.12

Comment: I understand that.  But what about `0,000,abcd12345.22abcd`.  What should that result in?

Comment: I'm just concerned about the initial part, if it has alpha characters in it I have an if block for that and I'm just throwing an exception for it

Comment: Well, I gave it another try.  I haven't explained how the loop works yet.  If you run it and print str after each transition you will see it works from right to left to place the thousands separator.